# WinAPI GUI: Is Status Bar possible with dialog box?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using dialog box-based Win API C++ GUI. Just read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bar-reference) and there is [CreateStatusWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-createstatuswindowa) API which is used to create the status bar, but I don't know how it can be fit into mine, because I'm using CreateDialogW.

CreateStatusWindow is obsolete, CreateWindow is recommended.

> Note   This function is obsolete. Use CreateWindow instead

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "resource.h"

// Enable Visual Styles
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

// Set Windows GUI Subsystem
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

// Required for LV_COLUMN and ListView_x
#include <CommCtrl.h>

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // Load icon
        const auto icon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 64, 64, 0));
        SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(icon));

        // Load menu
        const HMENU menu = LoadMenuW(GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1));
        SetMenu(hWnd, menu);
            
        // Add ListView columns
        LVCOLUMNW col{};
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 60;
        wchar_t c0_txt[] = L"Title";
        col.pszText = c0_txt;
        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, &col);
            
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return FALSE; // we didn't handle that particular `msg` completely, therefore we should return FALSE. It can also depend on `wParam` and `lParam`.
    }
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 448
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 213
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 455, 220
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,21,25,396,160
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MAIN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDR_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "Control Panel"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Exit",                        ID_CONTROLPANEL_EXIT
    END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Folder.ico"

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

## Edit (Fixed the chinese characters):

I was able to add it on `WM_INITDIALOG`, but unfortunately it doesn't resize along with the window's resizing and its encoding is chinese.

[image]

```
// Add Status Bar
RECT client_rect{};
GetClientRect(hWnd, &client_rect);

HWND status = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, 0,
    client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top - 20,
    client_rect.right - client_rect.left, 20, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance,
    nullptr);

int status_parts[2] = { client_rect.right - client_rect.left - 170,
                client_rect.right - client_rect.left };
SendMessageW(status, SB_SETPARTS, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&status_parts));
SendMessageW(status, SB_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(L"Test"));
SendMessageW(status, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You should be able to do it in your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler.

Comment: Dialogs are just windows, there's no reason you can't create a status bar control and add it after the dialog has been created.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I was able to do it, but with 2 issues: it doesn't resize and the encoding is chinese. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: In your dialog procedure you need to handle the `WM_SIZE` message and forward it to the status bar to get it to resize. Not sure what you mean about the encoding.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I fixed the encoding, it was `""` instead of `L""` in SendMessageW. About the resizing issue, I tried with `SendMessageW(hStatus, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);`, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a dialog from a resource template the system sends a [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog) message to the dialog procedure:

> Sent to the dialog box procedure immediately before a dialog box is displayed. Dialog box procedures typically use this message to initialize controls and carry out any other initialization tasks that affect the appearance of the dialog box.

If a dialog needs a dynamically created [Status Bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bars) control, that's where it should be created. Since

> the window procedure for the status bar automatically sets the initial size and position of the window, ignoring the values specified in the `CreateWindowEx` function

you can pass arbitrary values for `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`:

```cpp
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP,
        0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd,
        reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(IDC_STATUS_BAR), GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), nullptr);
    return TRUE;
```

For this to compile you will have to create a symbolic constant `IDC_STATUS_BAR` to act as a control identifier (used later when resizing). One way is to add it to the *resource.h* file, e.g.:

```cpp
#define IDC_STATUS_BAR 101
```

That creates a properly positioned and sized status bar control. Instructions on how to keep it in the desired relative position when its parent is resized are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bars#size-and-height) as well:

> The window procedure [for the status bar] automatically adjusts the size of the status bar whenever it receives a `WM_SIZE` message. Typically, when the size of the parent window changes, the parent sends a `WM_SIZE` message to the status bar.

Again, the status bar control ignores the width and height, so sending a `WM_SIZE` message with arbitrary values is fine. Add the following to the dialog procedure:

```cpp
case WM_SIZE:
    SendMessageW(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATUS_BAR), WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
    return FALSE;
```

and the status bar control will automatically follow its parent's client area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This was what I needed. https://pastebin.com/3E2CtDyZ - I added the text and status parts, they look okay?

Comment: Hey, what about this way: https://pastebin.com/np6V5rFc, because I also have a ListView to take care of.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clicking links to pastebin.com. If you do have a question, go ahead and hit the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 2):

For the last two questions:

From the fact that your `WinMain` accepts `LPSTR` (and not `LPWSTR`) - I assume that you are NOT building for UNICODE. Then [SB_SETTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sb-settext) requires an ANSI character string, while you are passing wide string here:

```
SendMessageW(status, SB_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(L"Test"));
```

You should either pass a narrow string:

```
SendMessageW(status, SB_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>("Test"));
```

or use `SB_SETTEXTW`:

```
SendMessageW(status, SB_SETTEXTW, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(L"Test"));
```

And for the position of your status bar - you create it at a fixed position within the client window:

```
HWND status = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAMEW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, 0,
  client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top - 20,
  client_rect.right - client_rect.left, 20, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance,
  nullptr);
```

When you resize your window - the status bаr stays at the same client coordinates. You should process the `WM_SIZE` message and move the status bar accordingly.

Comment: the question is how do I process the WM_SIZE, what am I support to write there?

Comment: @nop there is a pretty good example in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size

Answer (score -1):

You should only use `dialog-based` app if you need only the features provided by the dialog box.

As soon as you start adding status bar, menu bar, accelerators, serialization, etc. - you would be better off using a regular windows app.

Comment: I went for the dialog-based thing, because MFC apps seems to be using dialogs. Or their main window could actually be a window, not quite sure, I inspected one in Resource Hacker.

Comment: Why would *"serialization"* make a difference when deciding on a UI approach? Why would *"accelerators"* make a difference? What's not *"regular"* about a windows application that is based on a dialog? This is advice from a developer that thinks MFC were the Windows API. Entirely not useful.

Comment: @IInspectable, I also updated the question with what I did. There are two issues: it doesn't resize and chinese encoding.

Comment: @IInspectable -  you caught me, I was in fact thinking about MFC architecture. However, `dialog-based` app offers a trade-off between simplicity and features, won't you agree? And my general point is that you sacrifice more than you gain. As soon as one asks "how do I make dialog do <that>?" - I believe it points to the wrong decision to use that dialog app...

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. You express your opinion about the use of dialog-based apps, but do not answer the question about whether a statusbar can be added to a dialog. This might make a fine comment to the original question, but it isn't an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that we don't agree; I believe I did answer the question, by suggesting NOT to use dialog box for things that are NOT dialog box. Look at it as an `X/Y` problem: the person is asking how to do `X` when they need `Y`...

Comment: Sorry, no. *Is a statusbar possible?* is a pretty specific question, and you've not addressed that question at all with anything factual. As I mentioned before, this might be a great comment to the question, but it isn't an answer to the question asked.